# Can't determine what function was invoked so many times Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been looking at the cloud functions in my Firebase console, and I've notice for one day in the past month that I somehow reached 23k invocations. I initially thought to check because my billing said I was charged $0.02 for them.

I've searched high and low, inspected my billing, reports, logs. I can't seem to see what was called 23k times that day. Does anyone know where I can find this information.

Thanks!

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUaBi.png)

Comment: Hi! I'm having same problem right now, I now it is too late, but did you figure out what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no report that drill down a cost by each function for Cloud Function Billing. In order to see what functions are being invoked I would recommend that you keep some logs of usage of the functions, you can check how to setup logs in this [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging).

It's important to note that this many invocations of your functions should not generate any billing to you, since as you can see on the [Pricing Documentation for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#invocations), there is a free tier of 2 million invocations per month to all of your functions. So, for all your functions, you actually had at least 2 million invocations + 23.000 invocations that generated that $0.02 billing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't seen a spike since, but I was still curious what might have caused so many invocations without prompting. It almost seems like it's being misreported judging from what the logs indicate.